# Why the check for whether a service is running or not, is giving error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-service

I am using the function to find if a service is already running before calling it, so that the service is not started if its already running :-

```
private boolean iSR() {

        String sClassName;

        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
        {
            sClassName = service.service.getClassName();

            if (sClassName.contains("com.abc.def.Service_name"))
            {

                  return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
}
```

And I need to run the service in a separate process, as otherwise it will cause the application to slow down. Hence in the manifest:-

```
<service android:name=".Service_name" android:process=":my_process"  >  </service>
```

But if the service is running, and the function is called it will give error like this :-

```
..java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xyz.abc/com.xyz.abc.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why is it so? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure manager is not null? can you add a check there? There is no line number in the stack trace you provided, it is hard to predict what is going on.

Comment: Yes, manager is not null. The problem is occurring on executing the line ``Service_name.mThis.stopSelf();`` when the function (iSR()) correctly returns true when the service is really running. ``mThis`` is a public static variable (declared as public static Service_name.mThis = null ; and in 'onStartCommand()' mThis = this ; and 'onDestroy' mThis = null.

Answer (score 2):

A service that is already started (in your case the dedicated process has been created and onCreate has been called on the service component) won't be "started" again if you do startService from your client a second time (unless the service has either stopped itself or been killed by the system in a low memory situation). Your service will however get several onStartCommand calls.

So, normally you should not have to check if the service is running or not, the system will start and stop services based on if they are needed or not.

And, running your service in a separate process to speed up your application could be a sign that you were doing to much stuff in your application main thread. You should revisit your decision since your application will normally have a greater system impact if you have two processes instead of one.